# selecting both the group level and and child level in infragistics xamGrid

Tags: wpf, infragistics, multi-select

How can I select both the group level and and child level in infragistics xamGrid.

I have xamGrid with Parent Rows and child rows.  Currently I can select any combination of child rows or any combination of Parent Rows.  What I what to do is select some parent level rows and some child rows that are under other parent rows.  The control is not letting the  click select a child row if other parent rows are selected.  Ie Control + CLick  will not select ( highlight) a child row when any other parent row is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the very same matter is being discussed in the Infragistics community below:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/73836.aspx